# SQL select top if columns are same

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

If I have a table like this:

```
Id  StateId Name
1   1   a
2   2   b
3   1   c
4   1   d
5   3   e
6   2   f
```

I want to select like below:

```
Id  StateId Name
4   1   d
5   3   e
6   2   f
```

For example, Ids 1,3,4 have stateid 1. So select row with max Id, i.e, 4.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, depending on DBMS. Which are you using (oracle, mysql, MSSQL, etc)?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 8):

```
; WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STATEID ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RN
)SELECT ID, STATEID, NAME FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I gave this answer before the OP had specified an actual database, and hence avoided using window functions.  For a possibly more appropriate answer, see the reply by @Tanjim above.

Here is an option using joins which should work across most RDBMS.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StateId, MAX(Id) AS Id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY StateId
) t2
    ON t1.StateId = t2.StateId AND
       t1.Id      = t2.Id
```

Comment: This won't work as it is not necessary that records having id from 1,2----so on always have state, starts with  name from a to z in increasing order. Instead of applying max on name it should be applied on id column

Comment: @DeepakSharma Sorry, the question did not make it very clear.

Comment: "For example, Ids 1,3,4 have stateid 1. So select row with max Id, i.e, 4". this indicates that author want to get records of states with max id

Comment: And Assuming that id column is unique. There is no need of adding "t1.StateId = t2.StateId" check as it will always get max id for respective state

Comment: @DeepakSharma You're totally _wrong_ about the join condition, you need two checks here.  Otherwise, you would get every record in the result set.

Comment: @gofr1 yes this will work fine. I only said that there is no need of putting t1.StateId=t2.StateId as result will be the same if we only put join with id

Comment: @DeepakSharma Definitely it can! I guess with `StateId` added to query it becomes more understandable.

Comment: in term of optimization I suggest this should only be compared with max id of respective state. Even there is no need of selecting stateid in subquery.

Answer (score 2):

The following using a subquery, to find the maximum Id for each of the states. The `WHERE` clause then only includes rows with ids from that subquery.

```
SELECT 
    [Id], [StateID], [Name]
FROM 
    TABLENAME S1
WHERE 
    Id IN (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM TABLENAME S2 WHERE S2.StateID = S1.StateID)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() + TOP 1 WITH TIES:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
        Id, 
        StateId, 
        [Name]
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StateId ORDER BY Id DESC)
```

Output:

```
Id  StateId Name
4   1       d
6   2       f
5   3       e
```